# Is it possible to detect injected keystrokes?

Tags: c++, windows

I need to know if user input comes from a real keyboard or has been injected by some external app in order to "eat" fake keystrokes.

Detection and "eat" must be done from inside my program runnning in user mode.

Are there any way to do it?

Comment: What sort of access do you have to the machine? A HID USB filter could count the number of keypresses, and then confirm that there are an equivalent number of keys pressed at the application side. (You will need some kind of translation in numbers, as pressing "Shift" and "s" will produce "S" as the input)

Comment: @MatsPetersson: That wouldn't work. If I press `'a` on my keyboard, it may produce either `á` or `'a` depending on OS state.

Comment: @MSalters  Yes, that sort of modifier too - but you'd know if there are "NO keypressese" and "lots of input". Although I do suspect XY problem, and the actual solution is to do something that "only a real human can do" (e.g. involve a second device, view a picture and tell what is in it, etc), rather than detect "non-keyboard input". After all, someone quite clever could probably build a USB key-press generator too...

Comment: One warning: this probably makes you application unusable for people who rely on [Assistive Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assistive_technology). You probably should raise this with at least the Legal department. Intentionally making software unusable for disabled users sounds like a PR disaster waiting to happen, and the Sales department probably know about this restriction as well. TBH, this sounds like a stupid idea from a manager somewhere, and Legal may be a useful ally to dismiss this idea with prejudice.